# How to set UIButton image?

Tags: iphone, button, imagebutton

I'm new to iPhone.
currently i m working on an application in which,i have to add an image to a button.
i made the image with transparent background but it is showing white area instead of being transparent.
how come it would be shown as transparent.
I am creating the button through -(IBAction).

help is appreciated.

Comment: you must define button as custom and not round

Comment: We know your are new to StackOverflow but kindly do some search on google, you will get tons of answers having EXACT answer to your Question. You will be downvoted by others as some one has already did it. :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to add png image into your project which you want to add as button image.
Then choose button > go to interface builder > choose Type as 'Custom'

> select appropriate image from Image/Background option

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Its very **easy** Viveka :-
Follow these Steps

1) Create an **IBAction** for **Button** and **link** it with the **element** mentioned in **your.h File**.
2) go the **xib** of your viewController and select the button and go to the **Attribute Inspector (4th from Left)**.
3) go to the **Type** property of it and set it to **Custom** instead of **RoundRectButton**.

**NOTE :- If your Image is Transparent then you dont have to do anything extra for making it transparent**

If you are facing any problem plz revert, i would love to help it.